When I deploy my function app repository to a new app, it doesn't recognize any functions Azure/Python/FunctionApp
I created an Azure Function App using the VSCode plugin. It uploaded fine and the app runs as expected. I want to deploy the same functions to a new app, so I created a Function App and Storage Account using ARM templates. Then I wrote a new Github action that uploads the repository to the new Function App.
The deployment goes fine, and the Function App is properly connected with the storage account. But the Function App doesn't recognize the functions uploaded from the repository.
This is from my old Github Action:

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        env:
          TABLE_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{ secrets.TABLE_CONNECTION_STRING }}
        with:
          app-name: 'oldApp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true

This is from the new Action:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'newApp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true

I tried to stop/restart and reset the FunctionApp.
I searched and found suggestions to use the debug console, but my plan doesn't support a debug console.
I found suggestions to check the function.json file, but I don't have that file, and my original (working) Function App didn't have a function.json either.
I compared the configuration between the apps. FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION, FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME, WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING are all correct on both apps. The new one is setup with WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE, and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to the path to the latest Functionapp.zip.
The correct data is uploaded to the store, but there is no data in the storage account file share.
Github repo
The offending Action is on the "update-workflow" branch. I recently changed the Action on main to use the new app-name and PUBLISH_PROFILE with the old action script and received this error: https://imgur.com/a/iq49KiJ

Please share your repository link if possible.

https://github.com/jonalfarlinga/portfolio

You are able to deploy your function to Azure using GitHub actions, but unable to sync the triggers. Is my understanding correct?

I can see there is no local.settings.json in your repository. Create the file in the root directory with code {"IsEncrypted": false,"Values": {"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python","AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags":"EnableWorkerIndexing","AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"}}

I could deploy and sync the triggers in Azure. Refer Image1 & Image2

Sorry, I forgot to say the new workflow is on "update-workflow" branch.
Can you tell me how you started the FunctionApp? When I originally built the functions, I used the VSCode extension, and the autogenerated workflow. That workflow works. When I deploy an app using ARM templates, if I generate the Action, it succeeds but doesn't recognize the functions. If I change the PUBLISH_PROFILE and app name from the original action, it fails with this error: https://imgur.com/a/iq49KiJ

Enable SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials in Function app=>Configuration=>Gerneral Settings in Portal. Refer Image.

I have added local.settings.json in the root directory of your project and tested in my environment:
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
      "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}


Pushed the code to GitHub
Deployed the function to Azure using GitHub actions:

Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_123EC76XXXXF7E }}


Able to deploy the function app and sync the triggers in Azure:



To avoid Authentication 401 error as mentioned in the comments, enable SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials in Function app=>Configuration=>Gerneral Settings:


